# React Nextjs routing passing Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I have a react app that uses a redux store to hold data from a database. The home page has access to this data with the redux store. Other pages cannot access this data. I realize that I need to use a Provider component and have tried that, however I think there is something wrong with the structure as I am using nextjs for routing, and the code on the index page is not getting included.

```js
  //index.js
  
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <p>My Page Data</p>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
```

All examples I see use an  component but the template I am using does not use that and exports html directly from the index page instead. How do I have the index.js page as the top level component (holding the provider) and then have all pages as a child of this (so they can access the store). I am using React 16.3.1

Answer (score 2):

You should use HoC which wraps your pages with `Provider`.

If request comes from the server - new store is created and kept in a global variable on the client side. Every time when you are using client routing (for instance, `'next/link'`) it will grab this store from global variable and pass to the `Provider` component of another page.

It's already written and commented by Next.js team in [this example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-redux).

So, your typical page should looks like:

```
import withRedux from './utils/withRedux'

const SomePage = props => {
    return (
         <SomeLayout>
             <SomeContainer />
         </SomeLayout>
    )
}

export default withRedux()(SomePage)
```